# How to switch to HoTT-mode for Lean 2 in Emacs

Tags: lean, homotopy-type-theory

I compiled Lean 2 from the github repository. Then, as instructed in scr/emacs/README.md, I modified my .emacs file, opened a file, clicked on 'Create new project', clicked on 'Open', typed 'hott' and pressed Enter.

Then I typed

```
print eq.inverse
```

and I received a message

```
1:1: print result:

1:17: invalid print command
```

I also tried the command `lean-hott-mode` with the same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out.

Apparently, Lean requires HoTT files to have the extension *.hlean